# What is the "exptime" unit in "lcb_store_cmd_t"? Seconds, Milliseconds or others?

Tags: c, couchbase

I want to confirm the "exptime" unit in "lcb_store_cmd_t".

I can NOT get the definite unit information from lcb_store api html（here: http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-c-client-2.1.3/lcb_store.3couchbase.html）.

Although I have read the expiration explanation in the devguide (here: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.1/#about-document-expiration), I can NOT confirm that the exptime unit is seconds.

I want to set the expiry time as two days (172800seconds)， so I assign the exptime param with 172800, then call lcb_store. Is this OK?

Comment: I've also answered you at http://www.couchbase.com/communities/q-and-a/what-exptime-unit-lcbstorecmdt-seconds-milliseconds-or-others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is seconds. Personally I think the dev guide is quite explicit on the issue, but perhaps part of the ambiguity is that values greater than `30 x 24 x 60 x 60` are treated as absolute unix timestamps, and values less seconds relative from current time.

The [Python SDK reference](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-python-client-1.2.0/html/api/couchbase.html#couchbase.connection.Connection) explicitly mentions the unit is seconds.